# DNS для чего нужны записи NS

Tags: веб-сервер, php, hosting, dns

DNS запись выглядет вот так

ns1.site.ru 123.123.123.123

ns12.site.ru 123.123.123.124

Откуда берутся названия ns1.site.ru и ns12.site.ru ? и для чего они нужны?У меня отдельно сервер и отдельно регистратор

Если куча сайтов находится на одном сервере с одинаковыми ip адресами можно ли использовать одинаковые настройки dns? и что нужно написать, какое название ns придумать?

Поподробней напишите кто знает, без всяких ссылок на википедии и прочие нубские сайты

Answer (score 2):

> Wiki: NS = сокращение от англ. Name Server, название записи в DNS, указывающий на DNS-сервер (сервер имён) для данного домена; либо сокращённое наименование собственно DNS-сервера.

В Вашем случае - второе, т.е. ДНС-сервер какой-то компании (site.ru) и его нумер.

> Откуда берутся названия ns1.site.ru и ns12.site.ru ? и для чего они нужны?

Указано выше. DNS-сервер занимается тем, что хранит сопоставление имени компа с его IP-адресом.

> Если куча сайтов находится на одном сервере с одинаковыми ip адресами можно ли использовать одинаковые настройки dns? и что нужно написать, какое название ns придумать?

Можно, но при этом обязательно правильно настроить Ваш web-сервер. Написать нужно те, имена серверов, на которых зарегистрирован Ваш домен (mydomen.ru) и которые Вам выдал регистратор. Если записать "от балды" (читай придумать) - работать ничего не будет.

> без всяких ссылок на википедии и прочие нубские сайты

Уважаемый сударь, если бы эти "нубы", которые понасоздавали так претящие Вашей религии "нубские" сайты, в свое время не создали бы ARPAnet и другие сети, а так же компы, языки программирования и т.п. - то Вы бы сейчас не на пых-пыхе бы кодили, не мучились бы вопросами хостинга, да и вообще, в интернет бы не ходили.